# Virtualbox installation problem on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 22.04

Hello I am having problems installing Virtualbox on Ubuntu 22.04.
Ubuntu Kernel : 5.17.2-051702-generic

Output of resetting config:

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.17.2-051702-generic
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.17.2-051702-generic

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

$ sudo systemctl status vboxdrv
× vboxdrv.service - VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-09-06 14:10:59 -03; 9min ago
        CPU: 366ms

set 06 14:10:59  vboxdrv.sh[136567]: Starting VirtualBox services.
set 06 14:10:59  vboxdrv.sh[136549]: vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
set 06 14:10:59  vboxdrv.sh[136604]: This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
set 06 14:10:59  vboxdrv.sh[136604]: Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
set 06 14:10:59  vboxdrv.sh[136604]: for adding new hardware support to the system.
set 06 14:10:59  vboxdrv.sh[136604]: The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
set 06 14:10:59  vboxdrv.sh[136604]:     linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.17.2-051702-generic
set 06 14:10:59  systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
set 06 14:10:59  systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
set 06 14:10:59  systemd[1]: Failed to start VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The standard, supported kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 today is 5.15.0, but your error message suggests that you are running some out-of-band kernel that's both newer and *not in the Ubuntu repositories (anymore)*. Your Question should explain that difference, otherwise we'll just tell you to use the normal 22.04 kernel.

Comment: Removing kernel 5.17 fixed the issue.
Using now kernel 5.15.0-47-generic. :)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was:

```
sudo apt install gcc-12 --reinstall

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc -f

sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms
```

Kernel:**6.1-rc5** and **Virtualbox-7.0**